# Incrementing/Decrementing a number using checkbox

Tags: javascript, html

In my code, I need to add the value of the specific checkbox that has been checked to the span element. The problem is it's first clicks of the checkbox, the calculation goes wrong.

As you can see, if you click a checkbox for the first time, it substract the value instead of adding it. Is there something I forgot to add? My code is listed below. Thank you in advance

```js
const s = document.querySelectorAll('#enroll-subject');
        const cue = document.getElementById('cu');
        let cu = parseInt(cue.textContent.replace('Current Units: ', '').trim());
        s.forEach(cb => {
          cb.addEventListener('change', updateTotalUnits);
        });
        function updateTotalUnits() {
          let totalUnits = cu;
          s.forEach(cb => {
            if (cb.checked) {
              console.log("checked");
              totalUnits += parseInt(cb.value);
            } else {
              console.log("not checked");
              totalUnits -= parseInt(cb.value);
            }
          });
          cue.innerHTML = `Current Units: ${totalUnits}`;
        }
```

```html
    <div class="irreg-container" style="display:flex; flex-direction:column; text-align: center;">
      <div class="header" style="display:flex; flex-direction:column;">
        <span style="padding: 1em;" id="cu">Current Units: 15</span>
        <span style="padding: .7em;font-size:1.3em;">Checkboxes</span>
      </div>
      <div class="subjects" style="display:flex; flex-direction: column;">

      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td style="width: 100%;">Checkbox 1</td>
            <td style="width: 100%;"><input class="sbj-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="enroll-subject" value="4" id="enroll-subject">
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td style="width: 100%;">Checkbox 2</td>
            <td style="width: 100%;"><input class="sbj-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="enroll-subject" value="4" id="enroll-subject">
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td style="width: 100%;">Checkbox 3</td>
           <td style="width: 100%;"><input class="sbj-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="enroll-subject" value="4" id="enroll-subject">
           </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td style="width: 100%;">Checkbox 4</td>
           <td style="width: 100%;"><input class="sbj-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="enroll-subject" value="4" id="enroll-subject">
         </td>
         </tr>
       </tbody>
     </table>
     <div class="button-container" style="text-align: center;">
       <button class="submit"> Submit </button>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: You are looping over all your checkboxes each time, and for each one that is _not_ checked, you are subtracting its value. Not sure why it surprises you, that `15 + 4 - 4 - 4 -4` results in `7`.

Comment: (FYI: IDs need to be unique, you can not use the same ID on multiple elements.)

Comment: The thing is, If I remove the foreach combobox, only the first one is being functional. I thought that event parameter might fix the problem but I'm not sure how to implement it

Comment: I am looping thru a array on php to print all those text and combobox

Comment: @CBroe `you can not use`.  Well you can, it just doesn't make much sense.  Personally the only time I think they should be used these days is for anchor tags..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes no sense that you are looping over *all* checkboxes each time, and then subtract the value of those that are not checked - because you never *added* the values of those in the first place.

Just keep working with the *current* `cu` value, and then either add or subtract the value of the currently changed checkbox only.

```js
const s = document.querySelectorAll('#enroll-subject');
const cue = document.getElementById('cu');
let cu = parseInt(cue.textContent.replace('Current Units: ', '').trim());
s.forEach(cb => {
  cb.addEventListener('change', updateTotalUnits);
});

function updateTotalUnits() {
  if (this.checked) {
    console.log("checked");
    cu += parseInt(this.value);
  } else {
    console.log("not checked");
    cu -= parseInt(this.value);
  }
  cue.innerHTML = `Current Units: ${cu}`;
}
```

```html
<div class="irreg-container" style="display:flex; flex-direction:column; text-align: center;">
  <div class="header" style="display:flex; flex-direction:column;">
    <span style="padding: 1em;" id="cu">Current Units: 15</span>
    <span style="padding: .7em;font-size:1.3em;">Checkboxes</span>
  </div>
  <div class="subjects" style="display:flex; flex-direction: column;">

    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td style="width: 100%;">Checkbox 1</td>
          <td style="width: 100%;"><input class="sbj-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="enroll-subject" value="4" id="enroll-subject">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="width: 100%;">Checkbox 2</td>
          <td style="width: 100%;"><input class="sbj-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="enroll-subject" value="4" id="enroll-subject">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="width: 100%;">Checkbox 3</td>
          <td style="width: 100%;"><input class="sbj-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="enroll-subject" value="4" id="enroll-subject">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="width: 100%;">Checkbox 4</td>
          <td style="width: 100%;"><input class="sbj-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="enroll-subject" value="4" id="enroll-subject">
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="button-container" style="text-align: center;">
      <button class="submit"> Submit </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the headsup, I never thought I can use "this" get that specific combobox.